# Which design pattern to use to replace if condition in the c# code

Tags: design-patterns

Need to remove the if statement for the new instances , kindly suggest which design pattern to use. No case statement please

```
public ITrialBalance GetTrialBalanceReport(string param1, int param2)
    {

        if (param2 == 1)
            return new TrialBalanceReport().GetTrialBalanceLevel2(param1, param2);
        else
            return new TrialBalanceReport().GetTrialBalanceLevel2(param1, param2);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Strategy pattern usually replaces switch or multiple if statements

Comment: If this is your literal code, just DRY and remove the IF entirely, since both branches of the conditional are identical.

Comment: Patterns are meant to solve specific problems. They aren't generic design rules. What is the problem here? Why do you want to replace the `if` statement? Are you trying to "pick" a method to call? Shouldn't that be a job of the `TrialBalanceReport`? BTW both calls are the same here

Comment: Apologies , below is the code , the problem is there will be many if statements in the method and need some way to create instance of class based on parameters ::                                                                   
  public ITrialBalance GetTrialBalanceReport(string param1, int param2)
        {

            if (param2 == 1)
                return new TrialBalanceReport().GetTrialBalanceLevel1(param1, param2);
            else
                return new TrialBalanceReport().GetTrialBalanceLevel2(param1, param2);
        }

Answer (score 0):

If-else conditions are eliminated by using polymorphism. Your function which has all the if-else statements gets replace by virtual function in the base class. Each if-else condition has a corresponding derivered class which implments that virtual function accordingly.

The derived and base classes and function's parameters are expected to be more meaninful entities, not just numbers like param1 or param2.